# Using "of" or "in" near lessons

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

There is a novel and a tv series called "Lessons in chemistry". But usually I read "lessons of [any] language" instead of "in". Is it a nuance with the same significant or maybe it is related to the matter of study (hard science vs. humanistic)?

Comment: Can you provide at least one link with "of"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lessons in [subject matter; what is being studied or learned]

- lessons in chemistry or chemistry lessons
- lessons in French or French lessons
- lessons in flying or flying lessons [piloting a plane]

The preposition here is *in* and not *of*.

Comment: Google results: "lesson of english" about 795,000 results,
"lesson in english"4,210,000 results.
Ok, but near a million without the spelling checker?

Comment: No, when you google it, it says: About 2,230,000 results (0.44 seconds) when it's in quotation marks, and many hits are old-fashioned or actually worded like "English lessons", in fact. Fyi, the word English takes a capital e, like all languages and nationalities in English.

Comment: "The lessons of [war or chemistry of whatever] are that [etc.]" where lessons of means you learn something from the subject matter but not the subject matter itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: P.S. In Italian is different: people from Italy: gli Italiani. The language of the country: l'italiano.

Comment: [correction In Italian, it is different.' Why are you talking about Italians?